# One property for different types

Tags: c++

I have the following problem:

```
        extern Keyboard keyboard;
        extern Controller controller;

        class PlayerInputDevice
        {
        public:
            void SetDevice( DEVICETYPE deviceType )
            {
                switch( deviceType )
                {
                case KEYBOARD:
                    Device = &keyboard;
                    break;
                case CONTROLLER:
                    Device = &controller;
                    break;
                }
            }

            Keyboard* Device;
            Controller* Device;
        };
```

Obviously I cannot have 2 Device properties as different types just based on the fact that the assigning &keyboard and &controller would hopefully choose the correct property. (plus the ocmpiler doesn't like it)...

What's the solution to this problem: How do I have one property for multiple types?

I have played around with many different templating ideas but seem to never quite make it... I need a helping hand to open up a new path.

An example of me using the above would be:

```
class ControlState
{
    virtual bool Jumping() = 0;
    virtual PressingUp() = 0;
}

class Keyboard : ControlState
{
    // Implement those suckers
}

class Touch : ControlState
{
    // Implement those suckers
}

class Player
{
    PlayerInputDevice Input;
}

Player player;
player.Input.SetDevice( KEYBOARD );
player.Input.Device.PressingUp()
```

The above example could actually be that `ControlState` just has Boolean properties and that the `Keyboard` and `Touch` (in this case) could just have their input methods like `FingerMovedUp()` would then result in setting `ControlState` bool `Up` to true... but just example etc.

Comment: What's the real problem you're trying to solve? As it stands, an enum would suffice...

Comment: OMG! how does this work? explain more please :D IT COMPILES ATLEAST!!!

Comment: Unfortunately .PressingUp doesn't realise that PressingUp exists. I'll read up on void ptrs.

Comment: Using `void*` is risky since the compiler can't do any type-checking for you.  It can be appropriate as a hidden internal implementation detail of some classes, but it's not something you want to have scattered throughout your program's design.  An interface (class with pure-virtual functions) would probably be more appropriate in this situation.

Comment: Although my solution does not feel very clever anymore... I have avoid the void*. Thanks for the headsup

Answer (score 0):

If ControlState is expected to be the base class of all devices (make sure to use `public` access specifier as it defaults to `private`), as suggested by your example, then

```
ControlState* Device;
```

should do the trick.